# Is there any way to sign libreoffice document on ubuntu using ePass2003 Auto USB token

Tags: libreoffice

I am curious if there anyway to sign a pdf/document (libreoffice writer) using ePass2003 Auto usb token issued by emudra(https://www.e-mudhra.com)

Comment: Did you ask them? They have this at the bottom of the page to which you linked: *technical queries shall be sent to info@e-mudhra.com*.

Comment: @DKBose Yes, I did ask them, they have driver available which I have already installed and I can now see my certificate, However they are not trained or miss instructions for ubuntu and libreoffice. After driver installed, Firefox is able to identify the USB token but backup of certificate not working. In libreoffice it does not show any certificate/usb token. I have also changed certificate path to firefox instead of thunderbird but no success. Same working fine on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I work for Signer.Digital and it provides:

Free pdf signing service and works from Windows and Linux: [Signer.Digital](https://web.signer.digital).  The USB token or Smartcard is accessed on browsers using browser extension which is again free. Installation steps are given on above portal itself.  The similar software and libraries is available for Windows and Linux Ubuntu also for direct deployment or integration with user's web application.

Ubuntu extension host may be downloaded from Signer.Digital portal.

Answer (score 1):

When you purchase the digital signature from emudhra.com, they will send you a USB token. You would need to download the certificate on this USB token. On their website there is a [repository](https://www.e-mudhra.com/Repository/index.html) section which will provide you with driver library and pkimanager to access the certificate stored on the usb.

The driver is standalone, there is no need to install it. The readme in the zip file explains it well. Just mark the libcastle.so file as executable and add this file as module in Firefox trusted device as explained in the readme file. Libreoffice uses firefox ca settings.